# Simple Harmonic Motion - University Physics with Modern Physics problem 14.31

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator

I'm trying to solve problem 14.31 from University Physics with Modern Physics (13th E.) by Young & Freedman.

> Q: "You are watching an object moving in SHM. When the object is displaced $0.6\ m$ to the right of its equilibrium position, it has a velocity of $2.2\  m/s$ to the right and an acceleration of $8.4\ m/s^2$ to the left. How much farther from this point will the object move before it stops momentarily and then starts to move back to the left?"

The question is given under the subject of Energy, and I realize that there's both kinetic and potential energy in the situation.

$$E = K + U$$

$$E = \frac{1}{2}mv_x^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2=\frac{1}{2}kA^2$$

So far all I came up with is the angular frequency, which is related to both $k$ and $m$.

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

$$a_x=-\frac{k}{m}x=-\omega^2x\longrightarrow \omega=3.74 \ \text{[rad/s]}$$

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!  You don't know $m$, but this turns out not to matter, because if you substitute $\omega$ into your expression for $E$, you should find the masses cancel, and you can solve for $A$.

Comment: I see how m cancels out after substituting, thanks a lot for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially looking for your max amplitude, $A$. Then, using symmetry, you can find the distance.

You know the object is momentarily at rest when its speed is zero (i.e. it's located at $\pm A$).